# Get all users by department with API?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'd like to get users from a certain Department. I've been looking for a while and haven't found whether it's possible or not ...
I saw the http://spsite/_api/web/siteusers URL but it doesn't give us the Department.

Comment: By department you mean the group?

Comment: @uberz91 there's a user profile property `Department`

Comment: Use search REST API to get the users , Department should have an OOTB maanaged property to appply filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the user information list to get all the users for a site. Use: `http://siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/items?$filter=Department eq 'Value'`. This will return all the users with the department `Value` for that particular site.

Comment: This returns items from a list where the column `Department` equals to the `Value`. As long as there's not an OOTB SharePoint list including all users of the environment, this is useless.

Comment: What do you mean? User Information List is a hidden list available for every SharePoint site. Its how users and groups are managed in SharePoint.

Comment: Ah, you're correct! Wasn't aware of the hidden list.

Comment: @uberz91: User Information List contains information of only users which have logged in at least one time, user added in any sharepoint groups or user used in any User Field. So In Short, it will not contains all the users and that's why it is not appropriate way to get all the users.You can check this by creating one blank site collection and first check UserInformationList without doing anything in the site. You will get only one entry on that list that is site collection administrator

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela Yes, I'm aware of this. It will only work for a single site collection. In fact, I had already mentioned that in my answer. The OP had used the `siteusers` request in his call so I thought it was only for a single site.

Comment: Fantastic. I've tested it and it works. However, I had a little issue since I have French names on my lists, so I had to find another URL to get the list results. `http://siteUrl/_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=Department eq 'Value'` Thanks a lot !!

Comment: So that you know, I've realized that some users that have been deleted a long time ago are still here. I don't know whether I should delete them manually or not ...

Comment: I get that sometimes. Might be a bug.