# Get all users from one department

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, jquery

In SP list we have to show tasks of all users from one department plus users which doesn't have any tasks.
Any idea how can I get names of users from one department?

I read a question and answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150749/get-all-users-by-department-with-api), but solution is not so good for us as it looks onto User information list, and I need all users from department whether they logged in or not into that site collection.

Answer (score 2):

---

You can use the REST API to expand the 'AssignedTo' column and filter based on the Department of choice. Here's an example of that query:

```
https://sharepointurl.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Workflow Tasks')/Items?$expand=AssignedTo&$select=ID,Title,DueDate,AssignedTo/Department&$filter=AssignedTo/Department eq 'Marketing'
```

Comment: Not sure how could do it. Don't want to brag but, example of yours would get only users that started workflow?

Comment: You would replace 'Workflow Tasks' with the List you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a list to display those users and their tasks you might consider using a search page, as that will give you a lot of ways to tweak your search queries and display templates

Comment: well, I can't say that to my superior :) But thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not, search is the king of Sharepoint from SP 2013 onwards,  and I guess it is common knowledge :-)